# setting properties on jQuery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

is it OK to temporarily set properties on jQuery elements to let other function know that something is happening to that element?

For example:

- a function is doing animations with a element
- the user clicks on something that triggers another function that will animate the same element

=> one of the animations will fail and screw up the css :(

So maybe it's better to set a property on that element, like `el.animating = true` while animations are running; this way other functions know what's happening and stop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`animated-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to test if the element is currently being animated before running your animations:

```
if( !$(this).is(':animated') ) {

    $(this).animate({/*...*/});

}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/AGmX8/

Comment: sweeeet that's what I needed :P

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two possibilities:

1. Use classes as flags. See [`addClass` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`removeClass` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [`hasClass` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).
2. Use [**`.data()`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to associate *arbitrary data* with elements.

You *could* set properties on jQuery objects, *but* this only works if you keep a *reference* to this specific instance. Every time you pass a selector to `$()`, you get a *new* jQuery object. Thus something like:

```
$('div').foo = "bar";
alert($('div').foo);
```

**does not** work.

Answer (score 1):

You mean using [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)? It's exactly it's purpose. To have temporary data you can access from other parts of your code without making a mess of global variables